# Array of structs returning random values?

Tags: c, struct, strtok

Okay so I am having a weird issue which I still cannot solve and I am beginning to go crazy. I am trying to call variables from a struct, but it is giving me random values back. I am currently calling my structs with

```
printf("%s %i %i %i %i\n", student[0].lastName, student[0].assignmentScore, student[0].quizScore[0], student[0].quizScore[1], student[0].finalExamScore);
printf("%s %i %i %i %i\n", student[1].lastName, student[1].assignmentScore, student[1].quizScore[0], student[1].quizScore[1], student[1].finalExamScore);
printf("%s %i %i %i %i\n", student[2].lastName, student[2].assignmentScore, student[2].quizScore[0], student[2].quizScore[1], student[2].finalExamScore);
```

but I am getting this back
[image: output]

The output that I am looking for is [image: output]

but if I change my struct declaration from

```
struct student student[100];
```

to

```
struct student student[3];
```

I get these random values back The output that I am looking for is [image: output]

I am also only using 2 students so 3 should be enough. Am I not declaring the array struct right?

This is how I am assigning my structs

```
token = strtok(buffer, search);
    N = atoi(token);
    int dividerCount = 1;
    int quizCounter = 0;
    printf("'%s'\n", token);
    while(token){

        if(count == 0){
            token = strtok(NULL,search);
            M = atoi(token);
            printf("'%s'\n", token);
        }

        if(count >= 1){
            for(j = 0; j < (N * (3 + M)); j++){
                int divider = M + 3;
                if (dividerCount == 1){
                    token = strtok(NULL, search);
                    strcpy(student[count - 1].lastName, token);
                    printf("'%s'\n", token);
                } else if(dividerCount == 2){
                    token = strtok(NULL, search);
                    student[count - 1].assignmentScore = atoi(token);
                    printf("'%s'\n", token);
                } else if(M + 3){
                    token = strtok(NULL, search);
                    student[count - 1].finalExamScore = atoi(token);
                    printf("'%s'\n", token);
                } else {
                    token = strtok(NULL, search);
                    printf("'%i'\n", atoi(token));
                    student[count - 1].quizScore[quizCounter] = token;
                    quizCounter++;
                }

                dividerCount++;
            }
            if(token)
                break;

        }
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: How is this related to C#? Please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: Also please don't show images of text, copy-paste the text *as text* instead.

Comment: What's `token`? What's `buffer`, `search`, `count`, `student`, `j` and `M`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Finally about what you seem to be asking about... It seems that you don't do any bounds checking of your array. If you go out of bounds of an array you will get [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Or possibly you don't initialize the elements you *think* you're initializing. Please use a debugger to step through the code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. That's how one usually solves problems like this.